# How to find skipped spark job

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

I have a spark job which runs every 10 mins and takes 5 mins to finish.Suppose by any external condition this job takes 15 mins then the very next job will get skipped.Is there any mechanism to find which hours job is skipped.
For Exa. Job starts at 9.30 and takes 15 mins to finish then 9.40 job will be skipped and 9.50 job will start and so on.How to find that we missed job at 9.40.

Comment: You could log message into log file. Then you could just use logstash (or splunk etc...) to parse and observe log file.

Comment: That's the job a of **scheduler**. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try changing the way the jobs are scheduled, so that the tool submitting the jobs checks for running jobs first, and then logs that it is skipping a submission due to an already running job. However, these are some other options.

**Option 1 - History Server**

This is the easiest and most direct option. The Spark History Server provides a UI which gives you all of the applications (runs), when they began, and if not still running, when they completed or failed. Please see Spark's documentation on [Monitoring](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html).

There's a shorter summary on setting up the history server: https://luminousmen.com/post/spark-history-server-and-monitoring-jobs-performance

**Option2 - Query Timeline Server (YARN)**

Please see https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/TimelineServer.html

**Option 3 - Parse logs**

As mentioned in one of the comments, you can search your logs. It is easiest if you have already integrated with a tool such as logstash.

If no such tool is enabled, you can try a simpler method of using logging from the scheduler on your cluster. Enable log aggreation if it's not already enabled. How you do this depends on if you are using YARN, Mesos, or some other option to run Spark. For example, if you are using YARN and it is configured for log aggregation, you can view all of the submitted application IDs and their statuses using `yarn application -list -appStates ALL` and collect logs for an application using `yarn logs <application_id>`. Then, you can make use of the timestamps and other information in the logs (assuming configuration files such as log4j.properties are correct).

**Option 4 - Record time elapsed in driver**

If the above are not an option (history server isn't set up and you don't have access, jobs don't run on the same cluster, or some other reason), you can record `val start = System.currentTimeMillis` at the start of your program, and then calculate elapsed minutes at the end, using `val elapsedMin = (System.currentTimeMillis - start) / 60000`. Then you can log the minutes elapsed, and/or send a message if `elapsedMin >= 15`. You may need to account for the application not starting on time. However, this method will be less reliable, since it doesn't account for longer-running jobs failing. I would not use this method by itself.

Comment: Thank you friends ,all your answers helped me to understand how to handle such scenarios with multiple alternatives,in my case scheduler is maintaining log of such missed jobs which we can monitor.Thanks again all of you for providing such wonderful different approaches.